# Rselenium error 'An element command failed because the reference element is no longer attached to the DOM'

Tags: rselenium

I am trying to scrape the following page:

https://www.dukascopy.com/swiss/english/marketwatch/sentiment/

specifically, the numbers in the 'span' tag, the percentages in the green and red bars. i am using rselenium and my code is the following:

```
checkForServer()
startServer()
remDr<-remoteDriver$new()
remDr$open(silent = TRUE) #opens a browser
remDr$navigate("https://www.dukascopy.com/swiss/english/marketwatch/sentiment/")
webElems <- remDr$findElements(using = 'css selector', "span")
#pretvorim v tekst
resHeaders <- unlist(lapply(webElems, function(x){x$getElementText()}))
```

it works until the last line, where i receive the error:

An element command failed because the referenced element is no longer attached to the DOM

what is wrong?